# git pull error: "fatal: cannot rebase with locally recorded submodule modifications"

Tags: git

I'm getting this error doing a `git pull`:

> fatal: cannot rebase with locally recorded submodule modifications

Googling for this error message essentially no results! That was a first for me.

You can see this error in the git source control here (to verify it is a real error), https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/pull.c#L961

I tried deleting all the submodules in the project, re-init'ing them, etc and nothing will let me do a `git pull` on the master branch.

Comment: It looks like you're using submodules. Maybe you could try getting them to a clean state before pulling/rebasing?

Comment: As I said I've deleted them, re-init'd them so there's no local changes to them.

Comment: Even when you run `git status` in the parent repo?

Answer (score 30):

Obviously you've set your `git pull` to run `git rebase`.  When you do this and have enabled submodule recursion, `git pull` checks to see if there are submodule changes within in range of commits that will be rebased, and refuses to run if so.

You can simply break this up into separate `git fetch`, `git rebase` and `git submodule update` commands. Rebase has no submodule recursion option and hence is not concerned here.  Or, you could run `git pull --no-recurse-submodules` to tell `git pull` not to look at any submodules.

> I tried deleting all the submodules in the project ...

You would have to delete the submodules *from every commit in the range of commits to be rebased*, which would replace all those commits with new ones that have no submodules.  Since you're likely to replace them all with the rebase anyway, that's not *that* terrible, but it's also not very nice to yourself—it will make you have to go restore them to every commit in the rebased results.

Comment: Shouldn't `git pull` refuse to rebase only if both my local commits and the new rebase point *both* have changed the submodule? I have a situation in which I'm updating some files outside the submodule and just because someone updated the submodule on the main branch I get these fatal errors which are extremely misleading.

Comment: It probably should. There is ongoing work on making submodules work better, so if it isn't already fixed (I suspect it isn't but have not checked) you could do some work on this, or see if someone in the community wants to work on it.

Comment: When you hit a commit that is skipped, take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905448/git-cherry-pick-and-then-rebase

Comment: @StarShine: the submodule issue is not tied to the skipped-commit patch-ID issue (though there are some cross effects here).

Comment: @torek ok, I'm not totally in the loop to be honest. I just had a rebase that failed due to submodules and then got hit by a skipped commit. I suspect more people will eventually loop through these posts to navigate the errors :)

Answer (score 1):

According to a [somewhat complicated email](https://lore.kernel.org/git/3D5F0B08-A4A1-4891-895F-54A4A437BDB2@gmail.com/), the problem is not due to a real issue with your repo or worktree, but stems from a **limitation of git** that will go away at some point in the future.

In most (all?) cases, the following should **resolve** the problem:

```
git pull --rebase --no-recurse-submodules
git submodule update --recursive
```

As soon as the rebasing and the submodule-updating are kept apart, git can cope with them alright.

If you have performed **local changes to any of your submodules**,
be sure to push those first --
possibly going through the same routine as above for
each submodule where pushing cannot succeed directly because other
changes from remote need to be incorporated first.