# Git cherry pick and then rebase

Tags: git

There's something I don't understand when I rebase after cherry-picking in git. 
Would someone please tell me what's going on?

### The scenario like this:

I am working on the master and topic branches as follows and the topic has two commits.

```
      C---D  topic
     /
A---B      master
```

I had a problem with the topic branch, so I decided to just cherry-pick D and merge it into the master. I create a release branch and cherry-pick it.

```
      C---D  topic
     /
A---B      master
     \
      D'  release
```

I merge release into master.

```
      C---D  topic
     /
A---B----E   master
     \  /
      D'  release
```

The base branch of the topic has changed, so I rebase it to the latest master.

```
           C  topic
          /
A---B----E   master
     \  /
      D'  release
```

Finally, the commit of `D` that cherry-picked disappeared from the topic.
This is the intended result for me. But I don't understand why git found them to be the same, even though the commit hashes are different.

Answer (score 20):

A cherry-pick would change the metadata associates to a commit (like the date or its parent).
But it would not change its content (the tree SHA1 it references)

As explained in "[How does `git rebase` skip the commit which its change already has in upstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52790107/6309)", the patch id associated to the commit `D` is the same as `D'`, which is already merged.
So it is not repeated by the rebase.

With [Git 2.34 (Q4 2021)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/767a4ca648f8791c1fb623bd9f79fd8d7f026499), you will actually see those skipped commits, as rebase will tell you:

```
skipped previously applied commit xxx
use git rebase --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits
```

From the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---reapply-cherry-picks):

> ### --reapply-cherry-picks
>
> ### --no-reapply-cherry-picks
>
> Reapply all clean cherry-picks of any upstream commit instead of preemptively dropping them. (If these commits then become empty after rebasing, because they contain a subset of already upstream changes, the behavior towards them is controlled by the --empty flag.)
>
> By default (or if `--no-reapply-cherry-picks` is given), these commits will be automatically dropped.
> Because this necessitates reading all upstream commits, this can be expensive in repos with a large number of upstream commits that need to be read.
> When using the merge backend, warnings will be issued for each dropped commit (unless `--quiet` is given). Advice will also be issued unless [`advice.skippedCherryPicks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-skippedCherryPicks) is set to false.
>
> `--reapply-cherry-picks` allows rebase to forgo reading all upstream commits, potentially improving performance.

Comment: To reword it : when rebasing, git compares the *diffs* generated by each commit, to determine if a commit has already been applied.

Comment: @LeGEC Indeed. The path-ID I reference is the SHA1 of the diff you mention (https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-patch-id.html)

Comment: thanks for the link. Out of curiosity : does git store the patch-id for each commit somewhere ? or are they recomputed when needed ?

Comment: @LeGEC From what torek mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52790107/6309, it is computed when needed.

Comment: note to self that git-rebase docs also give a useful explanation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.35.0#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---reapply-cherry-picks

Comment: @KayV Good point, thank you. I have included the relevant man page extract in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: To what command is "hint: use --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits" connected? "git rebase"? "git pull"?

Comment: @KenIngram rebase: this comes from the sequencer in charge to manage the sequence of commits to rebase.

Comment: Ok. what's the proper command that includes --reapply?

Comment: @KenIngram [`git rebase --reapply-cherry-picks`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---reapply-cherry-picks)